# In ICollectionOnSTLImpl implementation, can't access m_T or item object's members

Tags: c++, com, vb6, atl

I'm trying to implement a collections of objects via VC6 that can be accessed by a VB6 programs.  I haven't been able to make it come together.

I have defined _CopyVariantFromAdaptItf and _CopyItfFromAdaptItf (from "ATL internals").
Here are my defines to be used in my collections definitions:

```
#define CComEnumVariantOnListOfItemInterface(ItemInterface) \
    CComEnumOnSTL<IEnumVARIANT, &IID_IEnumVARIANT, VARIANT,_CopyVariantFromAdaptItf<ItemInterface>,vector< CAdapt< CComPtr<ItemInterface> > > >

#define ClassInterfaceCollImpl(ContainerInterface,ItemInterface) \
    ICollectionOnSTLImpl< IDispatchImpl< ContainerInterface, &__uuidof(ContainerInterface) >,\
    vector< CAdapt< CComPtr<ItemInterface> > >,ItemInterface*,_CopyItfFromAdaptItf<ItemInterface>,\
    CComEnumVariantOnListOfItemInterface(ItemInterface) >

#define ContainerInterface      IFields
#define ContainerClass          CFields
#define ContainerClsid          CLSID_Fields
#define ItemInterface           IField
#define DllRegID                IDR_FIELDS

typedef std::vector< CAdapt< CComPtr<ItemInterface> > > ContainerType;
```

and this the preamble for the container class:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE ContainerClass : 
    public ClassInterfaceCollImpl(ContainerInterface,ItemInterface),
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public CComObjectRoot,
    public CComCoClass<ContainerClass,&ContainerClsid>
{
public:
    ContainerClass();
BEGIN_COM_MAP(ContainerClass)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ContainerInterface)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
END_COM_MAP()
//DECLARE_NOT_AGGREGATABLE(CFields) 
// Remove the comment from the line above if you don't want your object to 
// support aggregation. 

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(DllRegID)
// ISupportsErrorInfo
    STDMETHOD(InterfaceSupportsErrorInfo)(REFIID riid);

// IFields
private:
    int GetIndex( BSTR name );
```

etc....

and in my attempted implementation, I'm trying to scan the included objects for a matching name that is accessed in the object's function pName().  Note that I'm showing two different approaches that I have tried:

```
int CFields::GetIndex( BSTR name )
{

    long count = 0;
#if (1)
    Count(&count);
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<count; i++)
        if (wcscmp( name, m_coll.m_T->pName())
            return (i);
#else
    std::vector<CAdapt<CComPtr<IField> > >::iterator itr;
        for (itr = m_coll.begin(); itr != m_coll.end(); itr++)
            if (wcscmp( name, itr->m_T->pName()))
                count++;
            else
                return (count);

#endif
    throw E_INVALIDARG_13;
}
```

If I try the #if (1), I get an error that m_T is not a member of "vector<...".
If I try m_coll->m_T, I get an error that "vector<..." does not have overloaded ->, which I would expect.
If I try the #if (0), I get an error that pName() is not a member of '_NoAddRefReleaseOnCComPtr

Thanks in advance for any help you can give me!

Vance

Comment: You know that VC6 is dead and unsupported? It even predates the 1998 C++ standard, its implementation of the standard library is also not compliant (no surprise). Upgrade, otherwise you are on your own. That said, I believe that some COM stuff overloads `operator&` ("address of"), wreaking havok on standard library templates that use this operator expecting a pointer.

Comment: Of course VC6 is unsupported.  But since VB6 is still so popular and there is so much legacy code to interface with, VC6 seems to work easier.  In any case, it must support what I'm trying to do, which is to supply a collection of objects (each of which may have it's own collection...) to existing VB6 programs.  And indeed, the next step is to go VC 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know I'm talking to myself, but I'm hoping to help someone else in case I stumble across a CORRECT answer.

Ok, I have a working system and based on the response to another question [How to retrieve object pointer from ATL collection of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589708/how-to-retrieve-object-pointer-from-atl-collection-of-objects), this is what I ended up with.  I added the line:

```
COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(CLSID_Fields, CFields)
```

between the
    BEGIN_COM_MAP(CFields)
and
    END_COM_MAP()
lines so that getItemObjectPtr would work.

I changed the ItemInterface back to IField and changed the GetIndex method to:

```
    long count = 0;
    ContainerType::iterator itr;
for (itr = m_coll.begin(); itr != m_coll.end(); itr++)
    if (wcscmp( name, getItemObjectPtr( itr->m_T )->pName()) == 0)
        count++;
    else
        return (count);
    throw (HRESULT)E_INVALIDARG_13;
```

and the method getItemObjectPtr is defined as:

```
CFields * CrecordSet::getItemObjectPtr( IFields *ppFields )
{
    CComQIPtr<CFields, &CLSID_Fields> pFields = ppFields;
    return (pFields);
}
```