# How to retrieve object pointer from ATL collection of objects?

Tags: c++, com, atl

I have a collection of objects that is defined as:

```
typedef IField                  ItemInterface;
typedef CComObject<CField>*     ItemClassPtr;
typedef CAdapt< CComPtr<ItemInterface> > ItemType;
typedef std::vector< ItemType > ContainerType;
```

and I have created several of the CField objects via a series of calls (ignoring hresult):

```
IField* ppField = 0;
hresult = CField::CreateInstance(&ppField);
ItemType spField = ppField;
m_coll.push_back(spField);
ppField->Release();
```

and now I'm trying to retrieve a pointer to an object so that I can call one of it's methods:

```
ItemClassPtr pField;
short type1;
m_coll[index].m_T->QueryInterface( __uuidof(ItemInterface), (void **)&pField ) );
pField->get_Type(&type1);
```

and it crashes on access violation at the get_Type call.
this was changed in response to a responder's post to:

```
short type1;
IField * ppField = m_coll[index].m_T;
CComQIPtr<CField, &__uuidof(IField)> pField = ppField;
pField->get_Type(&type1);
```

but it still crashes when I attempt to trace in the get_Type call.

Here is the preamble to the CField class definition:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CField : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CField, &CLSID_Field>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public IFieldAccess,
    public IDispatchImpl<IField, &IID_IField, &LIBID_SQLite02>
{
    friend class CFields;
    friend class CrecordSet;
public:
    CField();
    ~CField();

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_FIELD)

DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CField)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IField)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(__uuidof(IField), CField)
END_COM_MAP()
```

Please help!

Note that this question is an offshoot from a previous ATL question [In ICollectionOnSTLImpl implementation, can't access m_T or item object's members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524138/in-icollectiononstlimpl-implementation-cant-access-m-t-or-item-objects-member)
That more fully describes the collection class.  I have replaced the #defines with typedefs.

Vance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `QueryInterface()` to get a **class** pointer, only an **interface** pointer. And you can't type-cast an interface pointer to a class pointer, either. The only safe way to get access to the implementation class is to define a separate private interface that the class implements, and have that interface expose a method that returns the class object's `this` pointer. For example:

```
class CField;

interface DECLSPEC_UUID("...") IFieldAccess : public IUnknown
{
public:
    virtual CField* get_ClassPtr() = 0;
};

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CField : 
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CField, &CLSID_Field>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IField, &IID_IField, &LIBID_SQLite02>,
    public ISupportErrorInfo,
    public IFieldAccess,
{
    friend class CFields;
    friend class CrecordSet;
public:
    CField();
    ~CField();

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_FIELD)

DECLARE_PROTECT_FINAL_CONSTRUCT()

BEGIN_COM_MAP(CField)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IField)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IFieldAccess)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(ISupportErrorInfo)
END_COM_MAP()
};

CField* CField::get_ClassPtr()
{
    return this;
}
```

.

```
CComPtr<IFieldAccess> pFieldAccess;
CField* pField;
short type1;
m_coll[index].m_T->QueryInterface( __uuidof(IFieldAccess), (void **)&pFieldAccess) );
pField = pFieldAccess->get_ClassPtr();
pField->get_Type(&type1);
```

Comment: Don't I need to implement IFieldAccess::get_ClassPtr()?

Comment: The `CField` class implements the `IFieldAccess` interface.  The `CField::get_ClassPtr()` method is the `IFieldAccess::get_ClassPtr()` implementation.

Comment: That's what I thought, but I get a IFieldAccess::get_ClassPtr(void) not found linking error.  Note that I changed _interface to interface and I assume that IFieldAccessPtr is "IFieldAccess *".

Comment: It needs to be declared as pure virtual in the interface. I updated my answer.

Comment: Had to declare Release and AddRef methods as well.  Does seem to work.  Now the question is which answer is safest and/or fastest?

Comment: The other answer runs faster.  I don't know about the relative safety between the two answers.

Comment: I accidentally left off `IUnknown` as an ancestor for `IFieldAccess`, so I have added it. With that, the ONLY thing you have to do to modify your original code is add `IFieldAccess` to `CField's` ancestor list and `COM_MAP`, and add the implementation body for the `CField::get_ClassPtr()` method. Nothing else needs to be done.

Comment: Using `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(CLSID_Field, CField)` may be faster, but it is more of a hack. `QueryInterface()` is not mean to be used that way. My approach is the safer approach. Whether or not it is slower, I couldn't say one way or the other. But at least it preserves the intended behavior of `QueryInterface()` while still provided the needed access to the class pointer.

Answer (score 1):

You query with `QueryInterface` for `ItemInterface`/`IField`, so the pointer you obtain is of this type (supposedly, provided that COM object itself implement the method correctly).

So what you are doing next is an invalid reinterpret_cast from `IField` to `ItemClassPtr`/`CComObject<CField>*`. This does not work: by the line you have exception at your `pField` has invalid non-NULL pointer there.

Another problem you have here is a bloated reference counting: your raw pointer `ppField` receives a pointer with incremented counter, I don't see you are releasing it here, I suppose you might be managing reference wrong somewhere else as well. Having other reference counting issues on your code, you might eventually have a very much similar access violation on your code, if your object is already destroyed and you have a call on the pointer to destroyed object.

What is helpful to troubleshoot problems at this point is the call stack at exception position. From current description it is not clear how deep you are inside the `get_Type` call.

BTW, if you are trying to restore C++ class pointer from interface pointer, it is easy if no marshaling is involved and is likely to be a problem otherwise. To get `CField*` from `IField*` in absence marhshaling here you can do this:

```
IField* pField = ...
CField* pNativeField = static_cast<CField*>(pField);
```

Note that lifetime of class pointer is dependendent on life time of COM object itself, so it's much safer to do this:

```
CComPtr<IField> pField = ...
CField* pNativeField = static_cast<CField*>((IField*) pField);
// NOTE: pNativeField is valid until at least pField is released
```

This is easy, but assumes that `IField` you have on your hands is implemented by `CField` and nothing else. Otherwise, `static_cast` would succeed and get you a pointer, but it is going to be invalid. Another safer option similar to Remy's but easier to do is the following:

```
class ATL_NO_VTABLE CField :
// ...
BEGIN_COM_MAP(CField)
  //...
  COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY_IID(CLSID_Field, CField)
END_COM_MAP( )

//...

IField* pField = ...
CComQIPtr<CField, &CLSID_Field> pNativeField = pField;
```

This is simple and reference counter friendly. The `COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY` above creates a fake interface entry which exposes through `QueryInterface` a raw C++ pointer. This will return a `E_NOINTERFACE` error gracefully without crashing in case `IField` is implemented by something else.

Comment: First of all, I added a ppField->Release() to the create routine so that the reference counter is correct.  I added

Comment: And I replaced the object access with: IField * ppField = m_coll[index].m_T; CComQIPtr<CField, &__uuidof(IField)> pField = ppField; - pField still points to the wrong location.  I will have added the CField class preamble to the original question along with your suggested changes.

Comment: I looked at your `CField` code and updated my answer respectively (last code fragment), you need to copy the update into your code.

Comment: Specifying CLSID_Field seems to do the trick.  I've run into another problem, but at least I'm in the get_Type routine.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem with Remy's solution is that it's a hack either. `IFieldAccess` uses non-marshalable COM type (raw pointer), so it works only where this solution works - there is no scenario where it works safer in any way. More useless code dedicated to hack per se (you have to declare a separate useless class!), slower, no real advantage.

Comment: Back to your original question - you are a hostage of your solution to keep interfaces in the collection, if you kept original class pointers there, you'd need no hacks - this would be safe!

Comment: I build the Collection of interfaces because, I believe, that's what VB6 seems to expect when a collection of objects is passed to it.

Comment: As far as I understand the objects are only the ones you do yourself (fields), this is where you come to the question of restoring original class pointer. The safes is to store raw class pointers on internal collection, and when it comes to giving stuff away to VB - you create a enumerator and return interfaces there. This way you have no task of pointer restoration in first place. Otherwise, both solutions do equally fine and both are not 100% safe: having interface on hands does not guarantee that you can restore original class pointer.

Comment: That makes sense.  I was trying to avoid writing the enumerators, etc by relying on the CComEnumOnSTL and CollectionOnSTLImpl interfaces and ATL's built in implementations.  I'l look into implementing the enumerators and reverting back to collections of objects.  Thanks both of you (Roman R. and  Remy Lebeau) for your help in this!!